# Can you throw an exception to the parent thread

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I am supposed to implement a primitive multithreaded server that starts a new thread for each connection.

It should be possible that one of the thread gets the message to shut down the server.

Is it possible to notify the parent thread from one of the child threads to stop accepting new connections and shut the server down?

Comment: In regards to the densitiy of your question we can only answer 'yes'. The 'how' depends heavily on your code and the libs you use.

Comment: Create an `AtomicBoolean` in the main thread and give every thread a reference to it. On shut down this variable is set to `true`. Before accepting new connections check this variable.

Comment: pass a reference of main thread to each thread and call a method on the main thread (eventually create a `Listener` for that)

Comment: 'call a method on the main thread'...how?  Method calls do not change thread context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways for inter thread communication :

1. You can keep a shared state (root of evils in multithreading) and
   update it and let the main thread check that state several times
   (use volatile or barriers)
2. While creating worker thread you can pass
   an instance of main thread and if any thread at any point wants to
   stop the main thread it can call a method on main thread to stop
   accepting further requests (more optimized than previous solution).

Comment: point 2 can be expanded to pass an implementation of some listener alike interface with one method to be called to *stop* the main thread

Comment: Thanks - I went with passing a reference on the server's shutdown method to the child threads

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, you can have shared variable over multiple threads.

You could use boolean variable, let's say `exceptionOccured` or `serverShutdown`, which would default to `false` and in exception  handlers in each thread you set this variable to true.

In main thread, you will monitor values of this variable and do necessary work in case when this variable becomes `true` (i.e. stop all threads, etc.).

In order to implement this you must first read about [volatile keyword](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html)